# Different column different conditions

Tags: vba, excel

i have written a code to validate 3 different columns which perform different

Comment: So... what's the issue?  StackOverflow is a collaborative website to help with issues, not a code-for-you website.  Please clearly state the issue you're having, and if there is an error indicate which line and the error message you receive.

Comment: try [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for formatting/assistance issues

Comment: @Cyril. The issues are:- 1.Code is huge i want to get it compressed so that it can be executed quickly